# JSON encoding problem in IE6 and IE7

Tags: jquery, json

Can someone tell me how to change this `getJSON` request to a `.ajax` call so I can set the `contentType` option?

```
$.getJSON('json/showreel.json', function(data) {
    //get total number of JSON objects and generate random numder
    var total = data.length;
    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*total)

    //Loop through each of the JSON objects to check if matches random number
    $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {

        if(entryIndex === randnum){
            var info = '<div class="entry" style="color:' + entry['colour'] + '">';
            info += entry['title'] + '<br />';
            info += '<a href="' + entry['link_url'] + '">' + entry['website'] + '</a>';
            info += '</div>';

            $('#head-contact,#head-contact a').css('color',entry['colour']);

            //create new image object to preload image
            var img = new Image();
            //once image has loaded execute this code
            $(img).load(function () {
                //$(this).css('display', 'none'); // .hide() doesn't work in Safari when the element isn't on the DOM already
                $(this).hide();
                $('#showreel').removeClass('loading').append(this);
                $(this).fadeIn(3000);
            }).error(function () {
                // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
            }).attr('src', entry['image_src']);
        }
        $('#info').append(info);
    });
});
```

Many thanks,
C

Answer (score 1):

`contentType` is used to set the type of sent data. GET requests do not send data so you may be talking about the type of received data, this is changed using the `dataType` option.

Replace:

```
$.getJSON('json/showreel.json', function(data) {
    ...
});
```

by:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'json/showreel.json',
    dataType: 'application/json'
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: ...or if you have control over the response yourself, then you really need to change this in the server side.

Comment: When I add the code inside the success function it doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to give more information than "doesn't work". Did it crash with an error? Did it do something? Is the JSON in your response valid (jsonlint.com)?

Comment: Ah. Got it sorted. there was just no response with data. Thanks